DXF line layer not rendering in Freestyle SVG Export
I'm working on a project in Blender 4.1 where I need to export lines as a SVG for use with my plotter. I am using Freestyle SVG Export.  I've imported a DXF file from QGIS, which contains line geometry, into Blender. The lines look fine in the viewport but are not visable in the camera view when rendered and do not export as a SVG. I have tried adding a skin, this makes the skin appear in the camera view but it is not exported as svg. Also i have pressed E in Edit mode and did some weird sliding thing and this also does not appear in the SVG. As well, i tried the wireframe modifier, however it appears to do nothing at all.
I have tested Freestyle SVG and it works when i create simple shapes in Blender but not when I import lines from a DXF file. The lines are very simple it should not take long to export. I have a super fast computer, total overkill, so its not that either.
Does anybody have any suggestions or ideas?
